# jquery slider from directory

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to find a jquery slider which can be set to load the photos from a directory.

Can anyone recommend a slider capable to do this? Preferably with thumbnail enabled.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: jquery is client side so you cannot make it read a directory on the server. you will have to pass the directory contents from the serverside to the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can probably dynamically generate the list of images with PHP (@Jean, sorry mate, just not a fan of PHP between script tags - even tho is just for example purposes) and pick a slider from these places:

http://www.pixelzdesign.com/blog_view.php?id=55

http://developers.slidedeck.com/ - this should be what you are looking for but it costs money in case that is an issue.

http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/09/jquery-image-slider-plugins.html

Comment: Yeah i know. I started talking about MVC, and then I thought that **PHP between script tags** would be more self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you could see this the other way around, like the commenters above are saying.

Why not use PHP to scan a directory (with something like scandir()) and send the result to your views ? In your views, you then only have to output the result of the scandir in the configuration of whatever slider plugin you like...

Something like that:

```
<html>
<?php
    $mydir = "/pictures"
    $pics = scandir($mydir);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  myplugin.init(){
     pic_list: '<?php echo implode("','", $pics); ?>'
  }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I was only trying pot luck to see if anyone knew an already setup slider with this capability, if not we will have to create one using php or JSON to feed the slider, but in the ned of the day - stackoverflow is not the wrong place to ask - its one of if not the biggest Q&A website. Criticise me al lyou like, I was merely asking for someone who knew of a slider available with the above capabilities - that is all.

Comment: What you were asking did not make any sense, and you seem to know enough to understand that. So I tried to guide you in the right way, that's all.

Comment: Thanks Jean, I appreciate your comment and answer but how did it not make sense? jquery slider using technologies to load photos from a directory this can be done with php, JSON or AJAX - I wondered if anyone knew a plugin or something I could download - have you searched for jquery sliders online? there are millions!! - I replied mainly to the other comment which was not helping at all - thanks again